# How to rename individual column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to rename the column "P3Q03.1." to "P2Q03.1." in one of my dataframes. However, the name remains unchanged. Here is what I do:

`colnames(df[colnames(df)=="P3Q03.1."])<-"P2Q03.1."`

Here is what results:

```
    > df$P3Q03.1.
      [1]      Mein                          Mein
    Levels:  leer Mein

    > df$P2Q03.1.
    NULL

    > colnames(df[colnames(df)=="P3Q03.1."])<-"P2Q03.1."

    > df$P3Q03.1.
      [1]      Mein                          Mein
    Levels:  leer Mein

    > df$P2Q03.1.
    NULL
```

Both before and after the renaming attempt, trying to display column "P3Q01.1." works and displaying "P2Q01.1." does not. It is as if my renaming attempt does not do anything, but it also does not create an error message.

Comment: You can use `dplyr`. `df %>% rename(P2Q03.1 = P3Q03.1)`

Comment: The solution for me was: ```names(df)[names(df) == 'P3Q03.1.'] <- 'P2Q03.1.'```